# Правильное употребление слова «соответственно»

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при постановке в соответствие одного ряда однородных членов предложения другому (при помощи слова "соответственно"), соответствие устанавливается в порядке их перечисления?
**Возьми ручку, тетрадь и учебник и положи их  соответственно в пенал, портфель и на полку.**
Просьбу следует понимать следующим образом: ручку необходимо положить в пенал, тетрадь — в портфель, а учебник — на полку. Если я не прав, поправьте меня.
Если же я все верно понимаю, помогите, пожалуйста, найти этому подтверждение в специальной литературе.

Comment: Возьми ручку, тетрадь и учебник и положи их соответственно в пенал, портфель и на полку. <=> Возьми ручку и положи её в пенал. Возьми тетрадь и положи её в портфель. Возьми учебник и положи его на полку.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "соответственно" в данном случае является предлогом и, согласно толковым словарям, имеет значение "согласно, сообразно чему-л., в зависимости от чего-л.".

В приведенном примере такая сообразность задается порядком перечисления предметов в двух рядах однородных членов.

Comment: Найти бы литературный источник, в котором это правило закреплено.

Comment: "Соответственно" - предлог? _Возьми ручку, тетрадь и учебник и положи их соответственно в пенал, портфель и на полку._ - _Возьми ручку, тетрадь и учебник и положи их в пенал, портфель и на полку соответственно._ Какой же это предлог, если его можно так просто взять и переставить в конец предложения?

Answer (score 0):

[соответственно](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE)
**I. наречие**
**1.** Равным образом, в равной мере; тоже, также. *Почвы бывают разные, соответственно различны и способы их обработки.*
**2.** *Разг.* Так, как следует, требуется; надлежащим образом. *Узнай решение и поступай соответственно.*
**II. предлог.** *чему.* Согласно, сообразно чему-либо, в зависимости от чего-либо. *Поступай соответственно своим убеждениям.*
**III. частица.** *Разг.* Да, конечно. *Брат уезжает завтра, а ты? — Соответственно.*
**<Соответственно с** *чем.* **в зн. предлога.** Согласно, сообразно чему-либо, в зависимости от чего-либо. *Поступай соответственно с условиями, с обстоятельствами.*

В Вашем предложении *соответственно* является наречием, имеет значение "соответствующим образом", зависит от глагола-сказуемого и обозначает признак действия (*положи **как?***). Ваши рассуждения правильны.

После предлога требуется постановка существительного в Д. п. (*чему?*) или в Т. п. (*с чем?*).
*Ветер соответственно поворотам то утихал, то налетал с удвоенной силой* (Э. Казакевич).

[Слово «соответственно»](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/slovo-sootvetstvenno-vyidelyaetsya-zapyatyimi.html)